Grouping rows by categories avoiding repetition
I have a tab-separated file with two columns on a Linux machine. The first column contains names, the second column contains GO IDs (these are always of the format GO: followed by seven digits) separated by commas. What I need to do is to keep one name with one unique GO ID in each row only, discarding repetitiveness and multiple entries.
From this
Pr_g33687.t1    GO:0003735,GO:0003735,GO:0003735,GO:0005840,GO:0006412,GO:0022618,GO:0022625
Pr_g33687.t1    GO:0003735,GO:0009129,GO:0006412
Pr_g15244.t1    GO:0000978,GO:0003700,GO:0005634,GO:0006357,GO:0034605
Pr_g15244.t1    GO:0003700,GO:0006355,GO:0043565
Pr_g15244.t1    GO:0003700,GO:0006355,GO:0043565

Into this
Pr_g33687.t1    GO:0003735,GO:0005840,GO:0006412,GO:0022618,GO:0022625,GO:0009129
Pr_g15244.t1    GO:0000978,GO:0003700,GO:0005634,GO:0006357,GO:0034605,GO:0006355,GO:0043565

I would appreciate your help. Thank you.
RS

Please indicate what you already tried and where you faced problems. That way you can avoid getting answers that you alread know won't work, and contributors get an idea what tools you have at your disposal.

What should happen with the "GO:000375" lines?

With awk and datamash:
$ awk -F'\t' '{n=split($2,a,","); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print $1 FS a[i]}' ip.txt | datamash -g1 unique 2
Pr_g33687.t1    GO:0003735,GO:0005840,GO:0006412,GO:0009129,GO:0022618,GO:0022625
Pr_g15244.t1    GO:0000978,GO:0003700,GO:0005634,GO:0006355,GO:0006357,GO:0034605,GO:0043565

The awk command splits the input such that the comma separated values are in separate lines instead of being grouped.
The datamash command then groups them back together and drops the duplicates.

Thanks so much. Your script worked beautifully. The explanations are useful too.

Sundeep's answer is tidier than doing all the work in awk. This uses GNU awk specifically for arrays-of-arrays
gawk -F'[\t,]' '
    { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) data[$1][$i] = 1 }
    END {
        for (name in data) {
            printf "%s\t", name
            sep=""
            for (go in data[name]) {
                printf "%s%s", sep, go
                sep = ","
            }
            print ""
        }
    }
' file

Pr_g15244.t1    GO:0006355,GO:0003700,GO:0006357,GO:0043565,GO:0000978,GO:0005634,GO:0034605
Pr_g33687.t1    GO:0022625,GO:0005840,GO:0022618,GO:0003735,GO:0009129,GO:0006412

Note that this does not preserve the order of the input GO numbers. You can sort the results by adding this to the END block:
PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"


Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly. It's useful to know how to arrive to similar results with awk alone.

This question shares elements with Expanding comma separated list in a tab-delimited file into separate lines and you could use a similar approach in Miller to explode, uniquify, then implode the data:
$ mlr --nidx --fs tab nest --evar ',' -f 2 then uniq -a then nest --ivar ',' -f 2 file
Pr_g33687.t1    GO:0003735,GO:0005840,GO:0006412,GO:0022618,GO:0022625,GO:0009129
Pr_g15244.t1    GO:0000978,GO:0003700,GO:0005634,GO:0006357,GO:0034605,GO:0006355,GO:0043565


Thanks for your help. It's instructive to know how to obtain similar results with different methods.

Using any version of the mandatory POSIX tools awk and sort implementing a variation of the Decorate-Sort-Undecorate idiom if you don't mind the $1 and $2 output order being different from the input order (they'll be sorted alphabetically in the output):
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -F'[\t,]' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i++ ) print $1, $i }' "${@:--}" |
sort -u |
awk -v OFS='\t' '
    $1 != prev {
        printf "%s%s", (NR>1 ? ORS : ""), $1
        sep = OFS
        prev = $1
    }
    {
        printf "%s%s", sep, $2
        sep = ","
    }
    END { print "" }
'


$ ./tst.sh file
Pr_g15244.t1    GO:0000978,GO:0003700,GO:0005634,GO:0006355,GO:0006357,GO:0034605,GO:0043565
Pr_g33687.t1    GO:0003735,GO:0005840,GO:0006412,GO:0009129,GO:0022618,GO:0022625

Alternatively, assuming the input is grouped by $1 values as shown in the example in the question, using just any awk, only storing the data for one $1 at a time in memory and outputting the $1 and $2 values in the same order they appeared in the input:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -F'[\t,]' -v OFS='\t' '
    $1 != prev {
        if ( NR > 1 ) {
            print out
        }
        out = prev = $1
        sep = OFS
        delete seen
    }
    {
        for ( i=2; i<= NF; i++ ) {
            if ( !seen[$i]++ ) {
                out = out sep $i
                sep = ","
            }
        }
    }
    END { print out }
' "${@:--}"


$ ./tst.sh file
Pr_g33687.t1    GO:0003735,GO:0005840,GO:0006412,GO:0022618,GO:0022625,GO:0009129
Pr_g15244.t1    GO:0000978,GO:0003700,GO:0005634,GO:0006357,GO:0034605,GO:0006355,GO:0043565


This is very resourceful! Thanks for your collaboration.

Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my %hash; 
             .split(/ \s+ /, 2) andthen %hash.append: .[0] => .[1].split(","); 
             END for %hash.kv -> $k,$v {put $k => $v.unique.join(",") };'  file

#OR:

~$ raku -e 'my %hash; 
            for lines() { 
                .split(/ \s+ /, 2) andthen %hash.append: .[0] => .[1].split(",") }; 
            for %hash.kv -> $k,$v {put $k => $v.unique.join(",") };'  file 

Above are answers written in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Raku (like Perl) has hashes/maps built-in. Because a property of hashes/maps is that keys are maintained unique, this  makes the solution fairly trivial.
In the first answer, the awk-like non-autoprinting -ne command line flags are used. This runs the code linewise over the input.

A BEGIN block declares the %hash.
The input ($_) is split on whitespace ( .split is short for $_.split) into 2 pieces. The andthen connector reloads $_ such that the .[0] the first piece is appended to the hash as key, while .[1] the second piece is .split(",") on commas which are appended as values.
After all lines are read-in and processed (i.e. at the END), the %hash is output, with unique-ified values.


[ The second answer is very similar to the first, except the specialized -ne flag combo is dropped. Instead the code relies on Raku's lines routine to read input ].

Sample Input:
Pr_g33687.t1    GO:0003735,GO:0003735,GO:0003735,GO:0005840,GO:0006412,GO:0022618,GO:0022625
Pr_g33687.t1    GO:0003735,GO:0009129,GO:0006412
Pr_g15244.t1    GO:0000978,GO:0003700,GO:0005634,GO:0006357,GO:0034605
Pr_g15244.t1    GO:0003700,GO:0006355,GO:0043565
Pr_g15244.t1    GO:0003700,GO:0006355,GO:0043565

Sample Output (\t tab between key and values):
Pr_g15244.t1    GO:0000978,GO:0003700,GO:0005634,GO:0006357,GO:0034605,GO:0006355,GO:0043565
Pr_g33687.t1    GO:0003735,GO:0005840,GO:0006412,GO:0022618,GO:0022625,GO:0009129

Of course, once you have the data in a hash, you can sort keys and/or values, and join on any separator you choose.
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org
